# Python how to generate a signed url for a Google cloud storage file after composing and renaming the file?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am building files for download by exporting them from BigQuery into Google Cloud storage. Some of these files are relatively large, and so they have to be composed together after they are sharded by the BigQuery export.

The user inputs a file name for the file that will be generated on the front-end.
On the backend, I am generating a random temporary name so that I can then compose the files together.

```py
# Job Configuration for the job to move the file to bigQuery
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.destination = table_ref
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
query_job.result()

# Generate a temporary name for the file
fname = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=10))
# Generate Destination URI
destinationURI = info["bucket_uri"].format(filename=f"{fname}*.csv")
extract_job = client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uris=destinationURI, location="US")
extract_job.result()
# Delete the temporary table, if it doesn't exist ignore it
client.delete_table(f"{info['did']}.{info['tmpid']}", not_found_ok=True)
```

After the data export has completed, I unshard the files by composing the blobs together.

```py
client = storage.Client(project=info["pid"])
bucket = client.bucket(info['bucket_name'])
all_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=fname))
blob_initial = all_blobs.pop(0)

prev_ind = 0
for i in range(31, len(all_blobs), 31):
    # Compose files in chunks of 32 blobs (GCS Limit)
    blob_initial.compose([blob_initial, *all_blobs[prev_ind:i]])
    # PREVENT GCS RATE-LIMIT FOR FILES EXCEEDING ~100GB
    time.sleep(1.0)
    prev_ind = i
else:
    # Compose all remaining files when less than 32 files are left
    blob_initial.compose([blob_initial, *all_blobs[prev_ind:]])

for b in all_blobs:
    # Delete the sharded files
    b.delete()
```

After all the files have been composed into one file, I rename the blob to the user provided filename. Then I generate a signed URL which gets posted to firebase for the front-end to provide the file for download.

```py
# Rename the file to the user provided filename
bucket.rename_blob(blob_initial, data["filename"])
# Generate signed url to post to firebase
download_url = blob_initial.generate_signed_url(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=10000))
```

The issue I am encountering occurs because of the use of the random filename used when the files are sharded. The reason I chose to use a random filename instead of the user-provided filename is because there may be instances when multiple users submit a request using the same (default value) filenames, and so those edge-cases would cause issues with the file sharding.

When I try to download the file, I get the following return:

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Details>No such object: project-id.appspot.com/YMHprgIqMe000000000000.csv</Details> 
</Error>
```

Although I renamed the file, it seems that the download URL is still using the old file name.
Is there a way to inform GCS that the filename has changed when I generate the signed URL?

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though all that was needed was to reload the blob!

```
bucket.rename_blob(blob_initial, data["filename"])

blob = bucket.get(data["filename"])

# Generate signed url to post to firebase
download_url = blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=10000))
```